# Shout box in MMO make new button and timers to limit shouts

Tags: javascript, mysql, css, sql-server, mmo

I would like to know how I could code in new buttons in my shout box menu in a mmo so that certain shouts can be turned off

Here is a list of the chat system

**General**
General chat is in white. It is at times also referred to as White Chat. This is the most simple of chats used to talk openly with people within your area. To use General Chat press enter and type and press enter to send. This can be blocked by blocking general.

**Whisper**
Whisper chat is used to speak privately with another person. To use whisper chat you can press enter and then type “/w Player name text.” This chat appears as a pinkish color. This can be blocked by blocking whispers.

**Shouts**
Shouts are used to speak with all players within a region. Such as Tullan, Delfaras, Limelight, Silancium, etc. The default color of shouts if blue but can be edited to different colors. To do a basic shout, the command is “/s”. To change the color of your shout you can use codes such as “/s <;HHFF0000> “to make red. These can be blocked by blocking shouts.

**Party**
Party chat is used to speak specifically with the people in your party anywhere around the map. It shows in green and the command is “/p”. This can be blocked by blocking party chat.

**Guild**
Guild chat allows you to speak with anyone in your guild and your entire guild is able to read it. To use this chat, use the command ”/g”. This chat is orange. This can be blocked by blocking Guild Chat.

**Union**
If your guild has a union guild or guilds (max of 3 in a union) you can use the command “/u” to chat with every person in the union. This is the only chat that cannot be blocked. This chat is green-yellow.

**Race Trumpet**
Race trumpets are viewed by everyone of your race and appear as pink. The command is “/race”

**Shout of Elemental**
These are special WC shouts that can be read by everyone on the server. They appear in yellow but the color can be changed as normal shouts can. This can be blocked by blocking shouts

**Warning of Ashtal**
Another special WC communication, a Warning of Ashtal can be seen by everyone in the game, on every server. These appear in red. This can be blocked by blocking shouts.

Problem is there is only buttons and controls for a few not all like below

EG: [Normal] [whisper] [Party] [Guild] [shout]

I would like to have buttons for all so people can control their gaming better.

EG: [Normal] [Whisper] [Party] [Guild] [Union] [Shout] [Scream] [Ashtal] [Race]

I would also like to control the time frame someone can use with a anti spam filter so if the same thing is said or tired to enter it will not be entered or blocked for a certain time

"Race trumpets"
"Shout of Elemental"
"Warning of ashtal"
"regular shouts"

Does anyone know of a way to do this ?

Comment: It sure is possible, it all comes down to schema design and to categorize your shouts.

Answer (score 0):

If your MMO provides an API or a chat option tool (ingame), then you might be able to
create chat windows and apply some filters to it.

Comment: this is strictly for the server side so players can make changes on the client side. It does provide the API but there are limited buttons and no code to stop people from spamming the same thing over and over again, the problem is the admin of the server has no clue and wont let anyone see the code to help make the changes. So I want to make a suggestion or give some code to make this possible

Comment: If you can't get the code, then you should do as you suggested : make an algorithm with "easy to understand" variables and a lot of comments. Perhaps you can search for others MMO chat system and then make some tests with network/system tools to get an idea of whats happening on your game. It may be useful to bring out relevant pice of code =)

Comment: Ya it is getting my hands on that relevant code that might be the problem The admin does not like to share anything but I will ask again to see. The client side ini files would be of no use right, as its just client sided we need this to work for the server side. My problem is I have no clue where to look for other mmo chat systems or where these would be or what keywords to use.

Comment: Usually clients do take care of incoming messages, otherwise it would be hell for the server to handle every single chat filter. If you don't want to/can't get access to your client code, then you will have to build a software that captures and drop/modify incoming packets from the server. To get an example of how a game can handle chat system, take a look at this well known [MMORPG API](http://www.wowwiki.com) (The Event API and sendchatMessage() function is what you are looking for)

Comment: When I say client I am meaning the players game client files. I can upload the ini files I have no idea what folder or filename the chat system files would be in,

Comment: I meant game client too :)  As you have access to ini files (easy to edit) just look for one dealing with event or chat. At this point I can't really help you given that the I don't know the game you are talking about.